# "There is no SINGULAR NOUN" and "There are no PLURAL NOUN"

Tags: negation, grammatical-number

I wonder if both of these sentences, "There is no frog" and "There are no frogs", grammatical in North American English.

From what I know, "no" can mean "not a/an" and "not any" based on the book, Oxford "how English works" (by Michael Swan & Catherine Walter). Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Your frog sentences are fine.  Your title needs an 'S' on nouns-  There are no plural nouns.

Comment: I wrote them in all caps to denote blank fillers.

Comment: No, you don't need an 's' on PLURAL NOUN because you're only referring to one plural noun!!!!  :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no frog with feathers anywhere on earth. Are you quite sure you saw it flying?

There are no frogs in Antarctica.

"No frog" can be more strident than "no frogs".  It would depend on the context.